# LibGDX: addActor(Body body)

Tags: libgdx

I get a little bit confused by the tutorial at this site:

http://williammora.com/a-running-game-with-libgdx-part-2/

Why is it possible to give a `body` to the `addActor` method?
Can someone explain me this?
I thought I must give it some Actor.

```
private void setUpGround() {
    ground = new Ground(WorldUtils.createGround(world));
    addActor(ground);
}

private void setUpRunner() {
    runner = new Runner(WorldUtils.createRunner(world));
    addActor(runner);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take again a look at the code. There is nowhere passed a `Body` object to the `addActor` method.

The only objects I see passed as parameters to the addActor method are runner & ground.
But those classes are extending the Actor class and not Body, see the code:

```
public class Runner extends GameActor { //..
```

and

```
public class Ground extends GameActor { //..
```

last not least the author of the code has defined the GameActor class like this:

```
public abstract class GameActor extends Actor { //..
```

==> you can see that those are subclasses of Actor and not Body. I hope it is clearer now.

BTW: if you use development environments like eclipse you can make use of the "Type Hierarchy" view!